# Are these two the same?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx

I am learning Mobx. when(predicate: () => boolean, effect?: () => void, options?)

As written on mobx:

```
class MyResource {
    constructor() {
        when(
            () => !this.isVisible,
            () => this.dispose()
        );
    }

    @computed get isVisible() {
        ......
    }

    dispose() {
        ......
    }
}
```

My question is that if I write as follows, do these two the same?

```
class MyResource {
    constructor() {
        when(
            !this.isVisible,
            this.dispose
        );
    }

    @computed get isVisible() {
        ......
    }

    dispose() {
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: One uses anonymous arrow functions the other does not

Comment: Yes, I tried. It works the same. But I can not ensure.

Comment: _Might_ differ as to what `this` context `dispose()` gets.

Comment: mbojko, your comment sounds reasonable.